# How to process %kernel.project_dir% from a .env variable?

Tags: php, symfony, environment-variables

I added this to my `.env`:

```
PHOTOS_DIR=%kernel.project_dir%/var/photos
```

Of course, when I try to retrieve the value of `$_ENV['PHOTOS_DIR']`, I get the raw string `%kernel.project_dir%/var/photos`.

But how can I get the value processed by the Symfony config processor, e.g. `/my/project/var/photos`?

*EDIT*:
I'm aware that it is simply possible to add this in `services.yaml`:

```yaml
parameters:
    photos_dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/photos'
```

But I would like to keep important config data in the `.env` file.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In order to expand `%kernel.project_dir%`, use `%env(resolve:...)%` in parameters, e.g.:

```yaml
parameters:
    photos_dir: '%env(resolve:PHOTOS_DIR)%'
```

Comment: Thats an interesting discovery, you got my upvote :)

Answer (score 3):

Your dotenv does not process the symfony yaml processor parameters.
Delete the %kernel.project_dir% from .env file and in your .yaml you need to bind a parameter like this:

```
photos_absolute_path: '%kernel.project_dir%%env(PHOTOS_DIR)%'
```

After that you can get the parameter from your container by the name of **photos_absolute_path** and it will point to the correct location

Comment: .env file is for the rather plain values config, you can keep relative paths there(eg /var/photos). If you don't want to use the symfony yaml processor(which I'm unsure why you wouldn't). You could create your own .env processor and invoke it in app/index.php in your public/web directory which would replace your own tokens to a certain value. @yolenoyer

Comment: At first, before posting my Q, I was wondering how `DATABASE_URL=sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/data.db` was processed, in `.env`. Your solution is ok, but I'm still wondering about it.

Comment: I believe some background magic could have been happening, DATABASE_URL is related to doctrine/orm, symfony/orm-pack I'm not familiar with the source code but I believe the database url parser could have something to do with that, I just tested this in Symfony 5.1 and it did not parse the parameter. So I'd bet that it has something to do with database URL parser

Answer (score 1):

Using symfony parameters in .env-files is correct. Symfony will automatically resolve them.

After container will be compiled, you can get the real value if you bind it to a parameter.
.env

```
PHOTOS_DIR=%kernel.project_dir%/var/photos
```

services.yaml:

```
parameters:
    photos_dir: '%env(PHOTOS_DIR)%'
```

Somewhere in your application:

```
$container->getParameter('photos_dir');
```

Comment: No, it's not working: `%kernel.project_dir%` is not expanded.